# Prove that If A is a real skew-symmetric matrix, then I + A is invertible, where I is the identity matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

In the Wikipedia article for skew symmetric matrixes the following propert is stated: If A is a real skew-symmetric matrix, then I + A is invertible, where I is the identity matrix.

However I haven’t been able to find a proof of this or why it does not apply to complex matrices.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix

This is different from the one where I - A is invertsble because this is I + A

Comment: Can we use the fact that $iA$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: I don’t believe this is a duplicate because that covers I - A and this covers I + A

Comment: A is skew symmetric iff -A is

Comment: Not only that, even if you didn't know that, if you go through the argument in the linked question and answer, you'll see it goes through essentially unchanged for $I+A$.

Comment: Technically the linked q/a doesn't answer one of your questions, namely about why it's not true for complex matrices. The answer has two parts, one is, it is true if we generalize skew symmetry properly to the property of being skew-Hermitian. The other is the proof requires an inner product (which is why skew-Hermitian is the right notion), and a nondegenerate bilinear form is not enough. A cx for complex skew symmetric matrices is $A:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \\ -i & 0\end{pmatrix}$, since $A+1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & i \\ -i & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, which has determinant $1-1=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigenvalues of real skew-symmetric are either $0$ or purely imaginary..

Suppose eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\cdots$, $\lambda_n$.

So, eigenvalues of $I+A$ are $1+\lambda_1$, $1+\lambda_2$, $\cdots$, $1+\lambda_n$.

Since eigenvalues of $A$ are either $0$ or purely imaginary, all eigenvalues of $I+A$ are $1+\lambda_1$, $1+\lambda_2$, $\cdots$, $1+\lambda_n$ are not equal to zero.

Hence, $det(I+A)\neq 0$. This implies, $I+A$ is invertible..

Note: If one of the eigenvalue of $A$ is $-1$, then one of the eigenvalue of $I+A$ is zero, and hence, $I+A$ is not invertible (as $det(I+A)=0$).

Take $$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & i\\
-i & 0
\end{array}\right).$$

Then eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $-1$.

So, eigenvalues of $I+A$ are $2$ and $0$. Hence, $I+A$ is not invertible.